# Use generic type in method TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript, I have the following code:

```
public static sortByProperty<T>( array: T[], prop: string ): void 
{
      var availProps: string[] = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( T ); // or something typeof T, anyway I got error

      if(availProps.length>0 && availProps.indexOf(prop) > -1){
          return array.Sort(function(a, b) {
               var aItem = a[prop];
               var bItem = b[prop]; 
               return ((aItem < bItem ) ? -1 : ((aItem > bItem ) ? 1 : 0));
          });
      }
}
```

and I want to use like

```
Test.sortByProperty<MyObject>(arrayOf_MyObject, "APropertyName");
```

I got error that `T` is unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not let the compiler do the property checking for you. You can type your `prop` parameter as `keyof T` and the compiler will enforce it.

```
class Test {
  public static sortByProperty<T>(array: T[], prop: keyof T): void {

      array.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aItem = a[prop];
        var bItem = b[prop];
        return ((aItem < bItem) ? -1 : ((aItem > bItem) ? 1 : 0));
      });
  }
}

interface MyObject {
  test: string
}

Test.sortByProperty<MyObject>([{test: "something"}], "test"); // OK
Test.sortByProperty<MyObject>([{test: "something"}], "notaprop"); // Error
```

---

To answer your original question if you want to check the property yourself, you have to pass a value to `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` something like: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array[0])` assuming your array has at least one item.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass array element to `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` not T.

T isn't available in Javascript anymore once it's compiled. It's only for Typescript. You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(array[0])` which should iterate trough all properties of your T object.